# Django: What's the correct way to get the requesting IP address?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to develop an app using Django 1.1 on Webfaction. I'd like to get the IP address of the incoming request, but when I use request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'] it returns 127.0.0.1. There seems to be a number of different ways of getting the address, such as using 
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR or plugging in some middleware called SetRemoteAddrFromForwardedFor. Just wondering what the best approach was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the middleware because this way I don't have to change the app's code.

If I want to migrate my app to other hosting servers, I only need to modify the middleware without affecting other parts.

Security is not an issue because on WebFaction you can trust what comes in from the front end server.

Comment: SetRemoteAddrFromForwardedFor has been deprecated so I can't use that it 1.1. Is there some other middleware you are referring to?

Comment: I just created a new one with my project, basically a clone of the django one. The reason the middleware was removed is the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR could be arbitrary on different hosting environments, so it should not be part of the django code base.

Answer (score 2):

The remote proxy middleware was [removed in Django 1.1.1](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.1/#id1) with a nod towards pointing out that trusting REMOTE_ADDR or HTTP_X_FORWARDED for isn't secure anyway (in case that also helps you decide what to do)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was hoping this wasn't going to be the case though. It doesn't really matter to me if the odd caller spoofs their ip address; the vast majority will be accurate. I guess I will just use HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR directly.